# How can I update a bit(10) datatype column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in the database named `active`. I has `bit(10)` datatype. I will be used for user's accesses. For example, the first character of that binary number points to user ability for voting.

Anyway, that column is defined like this:

[image]

But surprisingly it looks a 31-digit binary number which all digits are 1 and will not be changed to 0 at all. (the expected result is a 10-digit binary number)

[image]

Note: This query doesn't make any change in the result:

```
UPDATE users SET active = 101 WHERE 1
```

Anyway, why 31 digit? why that isn't changeable? And how can I get a 10-digit binary number which is changeable?

Comment: You can use normal decimal numbers or binary literals - `b'1010111'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the binary notation to Update or Insert your values :

```
 UPDATE users SET active = b'101' WHERE 1
```

I have tested and I can NOT reproduce your problem of bit(10) becoming bit(31).

I guess that phpmyadmin is not displaying correctly your wrongly inserted values

I would suggest that you output your values as `BIN(active)` and `CAST(active AS UNSIGNED)` to see what is the real binary value stored

Example

```
CREATE table test (id INT, tip VARCHAR(100), active bit(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL );

INSERT into test (id,tip) VALUES (1,'testing NULL default');
INSERT into test  VALUES (2, 'testing 0101 without "b" notation', 0101);
INSERT into test  VALUES (3, 'testing 0101 with b notation ', b'0101');
INSERT into test  VALUES (4, 'testing 111 ', 111);
INSERT into test  VALUES (5, 'testing b1111111111 ', b'1111111111');


SELECT id, tip, BIN(active) as binvalue, CAST(active AS UNSIGNED) intvalue  FROM test;

| id |                               tip |   binvalue | intvalue |
|----|-----------------------------------|------------|----------|
|  1 |              testing NULL default |     (null) |   (null) |
|  2 | testing 0101 without "b" notation |    1100101 |      101 |
|  3 |     testing 0101 with b notation  |        101 |        5 |
|  4 |                      testing 111  |    1101111 |      111 |
|  5 |              testing b1111111111  | 1111111111 |     1023 |
```

[Playground Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7c9c/1)

Answer (score 0):

Create 11 columns and store the data. Select 1st column as primary key and set it to auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 `column` bit(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```